# is there an API for Julia packages

Tags: api, julia

Hi I am an old Java/Haskell/Cobol programmer. And Julia has many fantastic features but I am struggling  with what I consider the basics. Particularly how to find what is in the many packages (Flux, Plots, DifferentialEquations, etc).

1. I have tried both VSCode and Jupiter notebook  and the Julia REPL but have found no way to extract this essential information while working on a program.
2. I have also failed to find the information on line without it being spread very thinly over tutorial for each package.

Is there and "cheetsheet" or "summary" or java like API?

Comment: "Sociologically", for lack of a better word, the thing is that Julia is very hands-on: a lot of (even mature) functionality lies in third-party packages on Github, and you are expected to read a lot of stuff from the Readmes and the code itself. Many packages do have good documentation (usually self-hosted on Github pages or similar), but many don't. The pro of this is that you get used to reading original sources all the time!

Answer (score 12):

For the basics, I would recommend two "cheatsheets" in particular

- "The fast track to Julia" https://juliadocs.github.io/Julia-Cheat-Sheet/ -- covers the language itself, the stdlibs, and a couple useful packages
- If you have previous experience in Python or Matlab, https://cheatsheets.quantecon.org

However, the package ecosystem is too diverse for any cheatsheet to cover all the useful packages out there, so for individual packages I would recommend a few tricks built in to the language:

- Tab-complete in the REPL. Typing `PackageName.<tab><tab>` will print everything in the namespace of `PackageName`, e.g.:

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> Statistics.

_conj               _vmean               covm                 quantile!
_getnobs            centralize_sumabs2   covzm                range_varm
_mean               centralize_sumabs2!  eval                 realXcY
_mean_promote       centralizedabs2fun   include              sqrt!
_median             clampcor             mean                 std
_quantile           cor                  mean!                stdm
_quantilesort!      corm                 median               unscaled_covzm
_std                corzm                median!              var
_var                cov                  middle               varm
_varm               cov2cor!             quantile             varm!
```

Note that since this prints *everything* in the package, this includes functions that may not be intended for general use. By general convention, any function beginning with an underscore `_` is not intended for public use.

- The `names` function -- will give you a list of all the functions *exported* by a given package (and thus is a bit more selective than just typing `PackageName.<tab><tab>`). This is effectively the public API of any given Julia package:

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> names(Statistics)
14-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :Statistics
 :cor
 :cov
 :mean
 :mean!
 :median
 :median!
 :middle
 :quantile
 :quantile!
 :std
 :stdm
 :var
 :varm
```

- Once you find a function that looks promising, the built-in help, accessed by just typing `?` at the REPL prompt:

```
help?> cov
search: cov convert StackOverflowError CUSOLVER has_cusolvermg code_llvm @code_llvm cudaconvert

  cov(x::AbstractVector; corrected::Bool=true)

  Compute the variance of the vector x. If corrected is true (the default) then the sum is scaled with
  n-1, whereas the sum is scaled with n if corrected is false where n = length(x).

  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  cov(X::AbstractMatrix; dims::Int=1, corrected::Bool=true)

  Compute the covariance matrix of the matrix X along the dimension dims. If corrected is true (the
  default) then the sum is scaled with n-1, whereas the sum is scaled with n if corrected is false
  where n = size(X, dims).
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
...
...
...
```

- The `methodswith` function -- will give you a list of all functions that can operate on objects of a given `Type`:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra, SparseArrays

julia> methodswith(SparseMatrixCSC)

[1] sizehint!(S::SparseMatrixCSC, n::Integer) in SparseArrays
[2] cov(X::SparseMatrixCSC; dims, corrected) in Statistics
[3] \(L::SuiteSparse.CHOLMOD.Factor, B::SparseMatrixCSC) in SuiteSparse.CHOLMOD 
[4] lu(A::SparseMatrixCSC; check) in SuiteSparse.UMFPACK a
[5] lu!(F::SuiteSparse.UMFPACK.UmfpackLU, A::SparseMatrixCSC; check) in SuiteSparse.UMFPACK
[6] qr(A::SparseMatrixCSC; tol) in SuiteSparse.SPQR 
[7] rank(S::SparseMatrixCSC) in SuiteSparse.SPQR
...
...
...
```

- On @OscarSmith's suggestion -- you can search for functions, types, and other symbols across multiple packages, as well as searching the full text of all Julia packages, on [JuliaHub](https://juliahub.com/ui/Search?type=packages). For example: [sprandn](https://juliahub.com/ui/Search?q=sprandn&type=symbols&t=function&u=define)

Finally, for getting a feel for what sort of packages are out there in the package ecosystem beyond the stdlib, I can recommend joining one of the several Julia community fora, such as the [discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/), the [slack](https://julialang.org/slack/), or the [zulip](https://julialang.zulipchat.com/register/).

Comment: you might want too add a line about juliahub's ability to search for functions across all packages.

Comment: Many many thanks. I may be showing my age but never would have found this out.  

Comment: There is also the function `apropos` to search for a function by keyword (which also includes loaded packages).